# How to insert a non-breaking space in Word online

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I am very new to Word/Office online - does non-breaking spaces not work in Word online? if it does, how do you insert one?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + Spacebar. https://www.avantixlearning.ca/microsoft-word/how-to-insert-a-nonbreaking-space-in-word/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said but I'm assuming you are on a Windows machine. Anyway the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> method doesn't seem to work on the online version from what I can tell. But I was able to get it work by entering the Unicode number for that character (0160) manually

To do this, hold the left <kbd>alt</kbd> key and type the numbers `0160` using the number pad.

Comment: It doesn't matter what OS you are on.
But thank you, this works! note for others you have to enter the first zero for the unicode - that is 0160, not 160.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with current Word Online version... (Windows 10, Chrome)

Comment: @hfrmobile: I tested again just now with Chrome and Windows 10 and it still seems to be working fine. Please see improved instructions in latest edit

Comment: Online Word in Chrome on Mac: `Option` + `space` works for me.

I don't know what is Unicode equivalent for Mac but `Option` + `0` `1` `6` `0`  is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Word for web does not support inserting non-stop characters, you can try it in the Word desktop program, Word for web is a free online application launched by Microsoft. It does not contain all the features of the desktop version, for inserting nonstop characters in the desktop version of Word, you can refer to this link:[Keep text together](https://%20https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keep-text-together-af94e5b8-3a5a%20-4cb0-9c53-dea56b43d96d)

Comment: Link does not work and if correcting it with removing https://%20 it looks like that the article doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment under the accepted answer because I don't have enough reputation, but if you're on Linux, you have to press CTRL + Shift + U, enter the Unicode for non-breaking space, which is `00a0`, and press Enter or Space. James' method doesn't work on Linux.

Comment: Thnx for your comments -- this is on Windows though.

Comment: Just wanted to add a disclaimer for Linux users who find this thread via Google and wonder why the top solution doesn't work like I did.